# URL Rewrite for IIS 7 IP to Domain name

Tags: iis

I have a request from a client that they would like for me to have this happen. When a user on the web goes to http://x.x.x.x have it 301 redirect to their domain name http://www.domain.com . I have messed around with rules in URL Rewrite and I have no problem specifying the conditions to determine the request for the IP address, etc. But when I do the redirect, the site goes into a redirect loop.

My question is how can I do this ? I know this is basically redirecting to the same place, hence the loop, but is there any way to make this happen ? For SEO reasons, they don't want visitors to the site to be able to get it via the public IP.

Thanks,
Chris
//////

Ok All, Thanks to some direction and good ideas from Caner, I was able to figure it out.
Here is the ASP code I used:

```
<%
if Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_HOST") = "" then
Dim rd
rd = "http://www.xxx.com" & Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location",rd
Response.end 
end if
%>
```

Thanks to all the suggestions!
Chris

Comment: I don't really know IIS, but it should be possible to create virtual servers. You might create one for the IP address (which only does rewriting) and one for the real web site (with the actual content). Hope this gives some useful hint...

Comment: Can you show us the redirect rule you have tried?

Comment: I could but I don't know if IIS will let me only bind a host header to a VS with no IP. I will take a look Ale. Cheese, I will try to dig it back up and post it, but I deleted it after trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a kind of tricky, but instead of configuring this on IIS, I suggest your client to add some code in their header file( header.asp file, site.master etc..);
This code can check the request; and you can reach `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`.
Using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`, you can do a redirect.

```
 string currentURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;

if(!currentURL.StartsWith("www."))
{
    string newURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
    if(currentURL =="www.x.x.x.x")
      newURL ="www.domain.com";

    newURL += HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

    Response.Redirect(newURL);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I assume it is an asp.net application.

Comment: Thanks Caner. I tried this. I had to re-write it as its a ASP classic app. But I got the same thing with the IIS URL Rewrite rule, just goes into a Redirect loop.

Comment: How about putting an if control before redirect, i have edited my original answer.